# Limit of ratio of incomplete gamma function

Tags: limits, improper-integrals, approximation, gamma-function, bounds-of-integration

In order to derive Sterling's approximation, I need to show that the following integral decays quicker than at least $\mathcal{O}(n^2)$:
$\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{\int_{2n}^\infty x^ne^{-x}dx}{\int_{0}^{2n} x^ne^{-x}dx}$ is at most $\mathcal{O}(n^2)$, this integral can be written as $\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{\Gamma(n+1,2n)}{\gamma(n+1,2n)}$ in terms of incomplete gamma functions. I have been trying analytical methods since a month but to no use. I tried to plot the ratio of this ratio to $\frac{1}{n^6}$ i.e. $\dfrac{n^6\int_{2n}^\infty x^ne^{-x}dx}{\int_{0}^{2n} x^ne^{-x}dx}$ vs n as shown below and so I am sure that it decays at least as quick as $\mathcal{O}(n^6)$, maybe it decays exponentially, however I need to produce an analytical upper bound for ratio. [image]

Is there some light? or some identity on incomplete gamma functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use some fairly brutal estimates. On the one hand,
\begin{align}
\int_0^{2n} x^n e^{-x}\,dx
&> \int_n^{2n} x^n e^{-x}\,dx \\
&> n^n \int_n^{2n} e^{-x}\,dx \\
&= n^ne^{-n}(1-e^{-n}) \\
& > \frac{n^n}{2e^n}
\end{align}
for $n \geqslant 1$.

On the other hand, with $g(x) = x^n e^{-x/2}$ we have
$$g'(x) = \biggl(\frac{n}{x} - \frac{1}{2}\biggr)g(x) \leqslant 0$$
for $x \geqslant 2n$, whence
\begin{align}
\int_{2n}^{\infty} x^ne^{-x}\,dx
&= \int_{2n}^{\infty} g(x) e^{-x/2}\,dx \\
&\leqslant g(2n) \int_{2n}^{\infty} e^{-x/2}\,dx \\
&= 2g(2n)e^{-n} \\
&= 4\cdot \frac{n^n}{2e^n}\cdot \biggl(\frac{2}{e}\biggr)^n\,.
\end{align}
Hence
$$\frac{\Gamma(n+1,2n)}{\gamma(n+1,2n)} \leqslant 4\biggl(\frac{2}{e}\biggr)^n\,,$$
i.e. we have exponential decay.